# Editing data in CSV files using Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file with the following data:

```
Time    Pressure
 0  2.9852.988
 10 2.9882.988
 20 2.9902.990
 30 2.9882.988
 40 2.9852.985
 50 2.9842.984
 60 2.9852.985.....
```

for some reason the second column is separated by 2 decimal points. I'm trying to create a dataFrame with pandas but cannot proceed without removing the second decimal point. I cannot do this manually as there are thousands of data points in my file. any ideas?

Comment: What's the expected output? To trim everything after the second decimal point?

Comment: Yes, that's right :) including the decimal point itself

Comment: So do you want to retain the decimal point so output should be `2.9852`?

Comment: The point being do you want to retain as string or convert to float?

Comment: Yes, I would like the output to be a float as you mentioned... 2.9852

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the vectorised [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) methods to split the string on decimal point, join the result of split but discard the last element, this produces  for example a list `[2,9852]` which you then join with a decimal point:

```
In [28]:

df['Pressure'].str.split('.').str[:-1].str.join('.')
Out[28]:
0    2.9852
1    2.9882
2    2.9902
3    2.9882
4    2.9852
5    2.9842
6    2.9852
Name: Pressure, dtype: object
```

If you want to convert the string to a float then call [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas.Series.astype):

```
In [29]:

df['Pressure'].str.split('.').str[:-1].str.join('.').astype(np.float64)
Out[29]:
0    2.9852
1    2.9882
2    2.9902
3    2.9882
4    2.9852
5    2.9842
6    2.9852
Name: Pressure, dtype: float64
```

Just remember to assign the conversion back to the original df:

```
df['Pressure'] = df['Pressure'].str.split('.').str[:-1].str.join('.').astype(np.float64)
```

Comment: Why joining it on `,` and then replacing that with `.`. Is joining on `.` directly not possible?

Comment: @joris yep you are correct, for some reason I thought I needed to match the comma that appears in the interim list, I'll update, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: That is absolutely fantastic. Thank you very much :)